# time rounding to nearest 10th minute

Tags: objective-c

i am using the following function to round the time interval to nearest 5th minute

```
-(NSDate *)roundDateTo5Minutes:(NSDate *)mydate{
// Get the nearest 5 minute block
NSDateComponents *time = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]
                                              components:NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit
                                              fromDate:mydate];
NSInteger minutes = [time minute];
int remain = minutes % 5;
// if less then 3 then round down
if (remain<3){
    // Subtract the remainder of time to the date to round it down evenly
    mydate = [mydate addTimeInterval:-60*(remain)];
}else{
    // Add the remainder of time to the date to round it up evenly
    mydate = [mydate addTimeInterval:60*(5-remain)];
}
return mydate;
```

}
now i want to rounded the time to nearest tenth minute .....
can any one please help me how to do that thing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you don't care about seconds:

```
NSDateComponents *time = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]
                              components: NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit
                                fromDate: mydate];
NSUInteger remainder = ([time minute] % 10);
if (remainder < 5)
    mydate = [mydate addTimeInterval: -60 * remainder];
else
    mydate = [mydate addTimeInterval: 60 * (10 - remainder)];
```

Comment: Thank you. Since you posted (~iOS4.0) addTimeInterval: has been depreciated and replaced with dateByAddingTimeInterval:

Answer (score 0):

My take at it, works well with other minutes as well tho i haven't tested.. heh

```
// Rounds down a date to the nearest 10 minutes
+(NSDate*) roundDateDownToNearest10Minutes:(NSDate*)date {
    NSDateComponents *time = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]
                              components: NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit |  NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit
                              fromDate: date];
    int unroundedMinutes = [time minute];
    int roundedMinutes = (unroundedMinutes / 10) * 10;

    [time setMinute:roundedMinutes];
    NSDate* roundedDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]  dateFromComponents:time];

    return roundedDate;
}
```